# Как в nginx можно указать несколько путей к директория статике

Tags: nginx

Как в nginx можно указать несколько путей к директория статике ?

```
location /static {
        alias /var/www/site/project/static;  
        alias /var/www/site/project/react/subdirectory/build/static;
    }
```

Comment: Вам нужен root и try_files

Answer (score 2):

Например так:

```
location /static/ {
    root /var/www/site/project;
    try_files $uri /react/subdirectory/build$uri =404;
}
```